# Request using HTTParty with API key

Tags: rubygems, httprequest, api-key, ruby-on-rails-6, httparty

I am trying to make a GET request to this [API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest), which works fine in POSTMAN. In my app I am using HTTParty to make the same request, and I am failing to structure the request correctly, resulting in a `{"statusCode"=>404, "error"=>"Not Found", "message"=>"Not Found"}` coming back. I've tried many variations but havent found the correct structure or naming of the parameters. This is for reference, where ENV["X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY"] is the enviroment variable holding my api key.

```
url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest/'

request = HTTParty.get(url,
  {
    headers: {
    "key": ENV["X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY"],
    "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    data: {
      id: 1
    },
    params: {
      slug: self.slug
    }
  }
)
response = JSON.parse(request.body)
```

this is how the API documentation suggests a cURL should be

```
curl -H "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: apikey" -H "Accept: application/json" -d "id=1" -G https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest
```

these are the screens from POSTMAN, where the request is returning the correct response.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P8Ok.png) [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkkOV.png)

I appreciate any input on helping me with this request. I am a newbie and the HTTParty docs have not been helpful, nor have I found any other similar examples.

Comment: This is not really a direct answer to your question, but I have an approach that I think may help you.  I was running into a very similar problem to yours while trying to access the eBay json-based APIs using HTTPARTY.  I tried for months, and even contacted the eBay developer team.

Right after I just saw your post, it occured to me that maybe the problem resides in HTTPARTY in some way (I'm not sure if that is actually the case), but I did a quick google search for alternatives and found Typhoeus , and I had it up and running in about 5 minutes: https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

Comment: The syntax for Typhoeus is almost exactly the same as HTTPARTY.  The only significant difference that I can tell so far is that one has to actually ".run" the request in order to trigger it being sent.  I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks @malikilam I was able to solve it with HTTParty. I still cant seem to figure out how to replace my API key there with the ENV variable, can you help with that?

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to resolve the issue.  I believe I can help with using Environmental Variables.  You can do that by first defining Environmental Variables in a file called your_application_folder/config/application.yml.  Just put the variable name in ALLCAPS and the value you are assigning to it (in this case your key) in this application.yml document in the following format: API_KEY: 08698h909j909e4de1eb9 .  Once you restart your rails app that will give you access to the variable everywhere in your app using the following syntax ENV["API_KEY"].

Comment: Make sure to add to the application.yml file to your .gitignore file so that your key isn't stored in your git repository.

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it didnt work for me, but I was able to solve it with the Figaro gem! I really appreciate your comments and help @malikilam !!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
headers = {
  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest'
params = '?&slug=bitcoin'
response = HTTParty.get(url+params,
  :headers => headers
)
```